# Reference Spring properties file using path relative to config file

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am moving properties from inside my Spring config file to a separate properties file.  This is included in the config file with

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="file:properties/${CONFIG_MODE}/service.properties" />
</bean>
```

As it stands, the location of the properties file is relative to the *current working directory* of the server process.

This creates the requirement that the process must be started from a specific working directory, and even worse allows for the (admittedly remote) possibility that it could pick up an entirely different properties file - for example if it was started with the working directory set to an older version of the service.

I'd like to reference the properties file using a path that is **relative to the directory containing the config file**.

Looking at [FileSystemResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html), it seems [createRelative](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html#createRelative%28java.lang.String%29) might be what I need, but I can't figure out how to use it in the config file.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that.

What you can do, however, is load the properties file from the classpath:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:path/to/service.properties" />
</bean>
```

The classpath location of your properties file is a far more predictable situation, and it'll work as long as your classpath is set up properly.

Comment: Nice solution - thanks.  The only problem (and I admit this isn't a serious problem at all) is that sometimes it's useful to be able to view/edit the properties file directly - eg in an emergency situation, or to do some quick testing.  Having it inside the jar doesn't prevent this, but makes it a little cumbersome.

Comment: @stevec: It doesn't have to be inside a JAR, file, it can just as easily be inside a filesystem directory that's on the classpath.

Comment: Will this work once I use `@Value("${thing.inside.service.properties}")`?

Answer (score 10):

Using 3.1, you can keep the files off of the classpath if you want.

With the following bean definition,

```
<bean class=
    "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" 
    value="file:${props.path}/service.properties" />
</bean>
```

you can set a property using the java command line

```
java ... -Dprops.path=path/to/where/it/is
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have placed the config.properties file inside WEB-INF
Then:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurerInternal"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
    <value>classpath:../config.properties</value>
</property>
```