# Access a Property file outside the classpath

Tags: java, spring

I need to access property file **outside the class path**. The file path will be in windows 
`C:\Temp\remote.txt` or in linux `/tmp/remote.txt`. How can my spring solution can access this 
file and read the content when starting up the application server.

How can I do this with 
Spring `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or with any other mechanism in my spring hibernate 
application

Comment: `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` accepts `file://` url in `locations`

Comment: @RC. post an answer maybe (providing links to official docs and all that, you know)?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611250/reference-spring-properties-file-using-path-relative-to-config-file?rq=1) for example

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I was looking for an existing answer instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/E:/Workspace/123.properties" />
```

Comment: This solution does not workfor me and giving INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9446e4: defining beans [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfiorg.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
 at 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Workspace\123.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Do you actually have the file in that location?

Answer (score 0):

#### PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

> As of Spring 3.1, `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` should be used preferentially over this implementation; it is more flexible through taking advantage of the `Environment` and `PropertySource` mechanisms also made available in Spring 3.1.

Using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` you can load properties from any path on the filesystem with:

```
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

configurer.setLocations(new Resource[] {
    new FileSystemResource(fileName),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use get resource as stream like:

```
String filePath = "C:/Temp/remote.txt";

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePath)));
```

I hope it helps